# Series expansion for function satisfying a functional equation

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, functional-equations

For example, if $$ f(x)^5 + f(x) = x $$

i.e. the solution $ s $ to the quintic equation $ s^5 + s - x = 0 $, how can we find a Maclaurin/Taylor series expansion for $ f(x) $?

According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse%20function%20y%20%3D%20x%5E5%20%2B%20x), the solution in this case is a hypergeometric function, which does have a series approximation, so how can it be found?

My attempt was to use implicit differentiation:

$$ \text{Let } y = f(x) \rightarrow y^5 + y = x \rightarrow 5y^4 + 1 = \frac{\text{d} x}{\text{d} y} \rightarrow \frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} x} = \frac{1}{5y^4 + 1} $$

so $ f(x) \approx f(0) + x \cdot \frac{1}{5f(0)^4 + 1} \approx x $ where $ f(0) = 0 $ by solving the original.

However this seems to stop working after the linear term as I cannot do a simple reciprocal of the $ \frac{\text{d}^2 x}{\text{d} y^2} $ to get the desired $ \frac{\text{d}^2 y}{\text{d} x^2} $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function (up to a sign convention) is called the [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical), and its Taylor series expansion can be computed using [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem). The answer turns out to be unexpectedly nice:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k {5k \choose k} \frac{x^{4k+1}}{4k+1}.$$

This can be interpreted in terms of counting $5$-ary trees as explained e.g. [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/update-and-the-combinatorics-of-quintic-equations/). (That post considers inverting a slightly different function but the two are related by a suitable change of coordinates.)